# How to run Dolphin as root?

Tags: kde, root, dolphin

I currently use `Dolphin 17.04.3` and whenever I run it as `sudo`, it gives the following error:

```
Executing Dolphin as root is not possible.
```

without explaining why or giving an alternative.

How can I run Dolphin as `root` for copying or deleting files?

Comment: are you using wayland? by default wayland does not allow GUI programs to run as root.

Comment: doesn't work. the option to create or move files is simply greyed out in the context menu. Please check  your version

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 17.10 and x11 with kde installed

Comment: Juan, I want to try your script, but I can't find a folder "kservices5" in .local/share. Any advice? I do find one with that name in usr/share, is that the one?

Comment: @ravery - it seems that the service menu available now (see my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415437/925128) has an option for wayland:  `if [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "wayland" ]; then xhost +si:localuser:root && pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dbus-launch dolphin %U && xhost -si:localuser:root ; else pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dolphin %U; fi;`

Comment: @Rinzwind - as of late Dolphin can be used as root again.

Comment: @cipricus cool,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Short:**

**Dolphin 17.04**

The Dolphin 17.04 or later has a check:

```
if uid == 0 then show the "Executing Dolphin as root is not possible." and exit.
```

**A workaround**

You could edit the sources and disable the check. Then the Dolphin will work as before.

**Dolphin 18.08**

**Few review request**

- Re-allow running Dolphin as the root user (but still not using sudo): https://phabricator.kde.org/D12795
- Show a warning when running as the root user: https://phabricator.kde.org/D12732

Dolphin 18.08.0 is using these changes and the Dolphin can be launched with the pkexec command as the administrative super user.

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dolphin
```

More: KDE Foruns - How to run Dolphin 18.08 as root with Kubuntu or KDE neon? - https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=153655

[image]

**Background:**

Earlier - KDE Forums - How to run Dolphin as root?: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=141836

For the security reasons: Disallow executing Dolphin as root on Linux - https://cgit.kde.org/dolphin.git/commit/?id=0bdd8e0b0516555c6233fdc7901e9b417cf89

> Disallow executing Dolphin as root on Linux Basically a copy of commit
>   kate/9adcebd3c2e476c8a32e9b455cc99f46b0e12a7e which was written by
>   Martin Grässlin

Disallow executing kate and kwrite as root on Linux: https://phabricator.kde.org/R40:9adcebd3c2e476c8a32e9b455cc99f46b0e12a7e

**More tips**

KDE Reddit - Dolphin root on KDE App 17.04 : https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6785b1/dolphin_root_on_kde_app_1704/

Bypass "Executing Dolphin as root is not possible" and Regain KDE Dolphin Root Privileges: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6xs3mp/bypass_executing_dolphin_as_root_is_not_possible/

**Future**

Polkit support in KIO: https://phabricator.kde.org/T6561

When it is ready the Dolphin will show the password query if needed. Now, with the patched Dolphin&KIO:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on the "For the security reasons"?

Comment: Did you read the https://phabricator.kde.org/R40:9adcebd3c2e476c8a32e9b455cc99f46b0e12a7e . Same / more : Martin Grässlin - Editing files as root: https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2017/02/editing-files-as-root/

Comment: so, the simple answer is "you cannot run Dolphin as root, unless you install a patched  version"?

Comment: @user47206: Why not patch it yourselfs ? ;) See my answer below !

Comment: I want to recommend a slight change in your command to run Dolphin as root. I just needed to add `dbus-launch` in the line to execute the command successfully. So the command becomes `sudo pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dbus-launch dolphin`

Answer (score 14):

Not an answer, just a workaround for the purpose mentioned by the OP (`copying or deleting files`).

The idea is to

1. install another file manger that doesn't have that limitation and that doesn't bring a lot of dependencies
2. create an "Open as root" context menu in Dolphin for this other file manager.

The main file managers of other desktops can be used (Nautilus, Nemo, Caja, Thunar) but they do bring some dependencies. Even PCManFM and PCManFM-Qt do that. If you need one of those for some other purpose adding that one could be a good solution.

I have found that **Krusader** (which I think in the past used to be installed by default in some KDE systems) can be easily installed, brings no dependencies in Kubuntu 18.04, and can be used as root.

```
sudo apt install krusader
```

Under its Tools it has the "Root" option.

[image]

which asks for password in a gui.

To add a context menu in dolphin, create the folder `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus` and then do

```
kate ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/filemanager_root.desktop
```

and add

```
[Desktop Action root]
Exec=/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesu krusader
Icon=dolphin
Name=Open in Krusader file manger as administrator

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=root
Icon=krusader_root
MimeType=inode/directory
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
```

For some reason `kdesu krusader` doesn't work, and I have used the solution from [here](https://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,129198.msg1088704.html?PHPSESSID=rbm3jeddt8ivqahkbmtdhcegf6#msg1088704).. What also works is `konsole -e sudo krusader`, but that shows the terminal instead of a gui for the password prompt.

Then, you'll see in Dolphin:

[image]

bringing a dialog

[image]

which is one that works..

Answer (score 6):

I have made my own version based on the replies above.
So, to add a context menu to **open Dolphin as root** follow these steps:

- Create a file called for example `DolphinAsRoot.desktop` on the directory `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`
- With a text editor put the following content on it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=root
Icon=system-file-manager-root
MimeType=inode/directory
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false

[Desktop Action root]
Exec=/usr/bin/pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dolphin
Icon=system-file-manager-root
Name=Open as administrator
```

- If it still not appears on the context menu in Dolphin go to "Settings -> Configure Dolphin...-> Services" and activate the option you recently added. It should be there. If not, close Dolphin or even log out and in on your session.

That's all, I hope it helps you all like it helped me ;)

Answer (score 5):

In current version (21.08.0) you can trick Dolphin by erasing the `$SUDO_USER` shell variable when running it with `sudo`. This simple command will work:

```
sudo SUDO_USER= dolphin
```

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial !

Just look at the source code of kate and kwrite:

```
diff --git a/kate/main.cpp b/kwrite/main.cpp
```

In the first lines of code directly at the start of the "main" function, you’ll find:

```
/**
 * Check whether we are running as root
 **/
if (getuid() == 0) // uid = user id = 0 ==> means if you are user 0 (aka root)
{
    std::cout << "Executing Kate as root is not possible. To edit files as root use:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit <file>" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Dolphin is no different, except this happens in libkdeinit5_dolphin.so.

So running as root is trivial, all we need to do is skip the if uid=0 check.

The way we do this, is by perma-patching kate, kwrite and dolphin.
So, the first thing we do, is dumping the binary content to a text-file:

```
objdump -Crd /usr/bin/kate >> ~/kate.txt
objdump -Crd /usr/bin/kwrite >> ~/kwrite.txt
```

Now you can look at the file with `gedit ~/kate.txt`, and if you search for getuid, you'll find something like:

```
   2a985:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2a987:   89 bc 24 dc 00 00 00    mov    %edi,0xdc(%rsp)
   2a98e:   e8 ed ce ff ff          callq  27880 <getuid@plt>
   2a993:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   2a995:   0f 84 e9 1e 00 00       je     2c884 <__cxa_finalize@plt+0x1f5c>
```

Now, on the left side, you find the memory address, after the colon (:) you'll see the binary instruction code (hex) and to the right of that, you see the disassembly of that code (aka what it means).

Now, you see, there it calls getuid, tests if that is zero and jumps into the if-statement, that is to say if the return value is equal to zero (je: jump if equal).

Now we don't want to jump into the if, so we just remove that crap there.
But just removing that crap would change addresses by 6 bytes, trashing any relative jumps in the program in the process, and as a consequence, the program. So instead you just replace the entire length of the jump statement with NOP (short for **N**o **Op**eration) instructions, aka 0x90 in instruction code/hex.

So you need to replace every jump byte there with 0x90 so where you previously had

```
0f 84 e9 1e 00 00
```

you will have

```
90 90 90 90 90 90
```

This can be done simply with a hex-editor. 
So we install one:

```
sudo apt-get install wxhexeditor
```

Now in the hex editor, you search for 0f 84 e9 1e 00 00, and replace that with 90 90 90 90 90 90. If there's only one occurency of 0f 84 e9 1e 00 00, and there is, then this is trivially simple. Just change the bytes in hex to 90 90 90 90 90 90 and save. Finished. Kate or kwrite will now open, whether you are root or not.

if you do the same with dolphin, you'll realize `objdump -Crd /usr/bin/dolphin` produces a very short disassembly.

if you run `ldd /usr/bin/dolphin`, you'll see dolphin loads the shared library libkdeinit5_dolphin.so

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc2fdf0000) libkdeinit5_dolphin.so =>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so (0x00007fb54e76c000)

So you do the objdump on libkdeinit5_dolphin.so:

```
objdump -Crd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so >> ~/libkdeinit5_dolphin.txt
```

Now open the objdump: `gedit ~/libkdeinit5_dolphin.txt`

Search for getuid, and you'll see that one of the search results is:

```
   41f95:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   41f97:   89 7c 24 5c             mov    %edi,0x5c(%rsp)
   41f9b:   e8 50 b6 ff ff          callq  3d5f0 <getuid@plt>
   41fa0:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   41fa2:   0f 84 58 1a 00 00       je     43a00 <kdemain@@Base+0x1a90>
   41fa8:   48 8d 84 24 a0 00 00    lea    0xa0(%rsp),%rax
```

This is great, you see, more crap just like in kate and kwrite. 
Now open `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so` in your hex-editor, search for `0f 84 58 1a 00 00` and replace it with `90 90 90 90 90 90`. 
Hit save, and done.

Dolphin now runs as root.

Note: Good idea to make a backup copy of the files you modify, just in case you f*** up.

Also, you could just download the source of kate, kwrite, and dolphin, remove that crap from the source code, compile and install. But since the stupid cmake system is missing some crappy crap template for some stupid crap such as icons, probably because the repo-supplied cmake is too old, this doesn't work. Too bad, would have been too simple if it just worked, wouldn't it.

But just patching the executables as I described is faster, so who cares anyway.

You see, it's not straightforward, but it's trivial.

PS: 
Now, any time kate, kwrite or dolphin are updated via apt, your changes will be overwritten. You'll need to re-apply them. I'll leave automatizing the patch-process in your more than capable hands, and your programming language of joice ;)

Can this be done in pure bash ?

Also, if you want to patch vlc for the same crap, you can do it with sed:

```
sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/bin/vlc
```

Just put that sed-statement into a script, so you can re-apply, if you ever need to if you are offline and have no internet access.

Happy hacking - with kate, kwrite and dolphin - as root - while watching/listening to something on vlc.

PS2: 
The crappy root checks went the way of the Dodo in KDE v19.04.
Who said **n**evolution was a bad thing.
To progress - Cheers !

Comment: Yes. Very trivial!

Comment: @Qumber: Replace some "text" with some other "text". I call that trivial. If it were a text file in notepad, you'd CTRL+H > text to search > text to replace > CTRL+A > CTRL+S > ALT+F4, and you'd be finished. Wouldn't even need a mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Kubuntu 22.04, Dolphin 21.12.3 accepts again being opened as root. There is a context menu service for that

[image]

Settings - Configure Dolphin - Context Menu - Download new services, search for "open dolphin as root"...

Or you can find it [here](https://store.kde.org/p/1384645). Put it into `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`.

The command in question is rather interesting:

```
if [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "wayland" ]; then xhost +si:localuser:root && pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dbus-launch dolphin %U && xhost -si:localuser:root ; else pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dolphin %U; fi;
```

Note that simply editing a file doesn't require that, as Kate can open any file and ask for root password when saving changes.

Answer (score 1):

You *never* need to run Dolphin as root! If you want to write to a protected  file, just go ahead and do it. Dolphin will ask you for permission. Then confirm the operation. I do this all the time.

Actually, I'll admit this isn't a perfect solution -- it doesn't cover the rare case where the file you want to edit is hidden, i.e., the directory it  appears in doesn't have execute permission. I don't know what to do in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Alls I did was add the Terminal to the toolbar (although keyboard shortcut bound to F4) and used the command line to perform operations as sudo as required.

[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl3qg.png)

Yeah it might not be as convenient but it forces you to start learning the command line whilst giving you visual representation of how the command actually works.

This is on Arch but the functionality should be the same on Ubuntu. Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

here it is a workaround for Dolphin 17.x:

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE; LD_PRELOAD=/home/roger/Downloads/dolphin/usr/lib64/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so /usr/bin/dolphin
```

get `libkdeinit5_dolphin.so` from [here](http://mirrors.xgroup.si/opensuse/update/leap/15.0/oss/rpms/x86_64/dolphin-17.12.3-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64.rpm)

Tested by me, it works fine in Ubuntu bionic.

[source](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kde-dolphin-as-root.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a suggestion.... Altering Dolphin and files is rather risky. Double Commander is an excellent alternative, and is found in the respository. It will install without root proviledges. To gain root, simply enter 'sudo doublecmd' in the terminal. It has many advantages when working with large and millions of files.

Answer (score 0):

Follow CallofCode's Answer
In my case, kde neon was not allowing install of any icons or themes and the only way was to cli copy files into folders which is unnecessary and tedious for basic things in 2022

> Create a file called DolphinAsRoot.desktop in the directory
> ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
> With a text editor put the following content on it:
>
> [Desktop Entry] Actions=root
> Icon=system-file-manager-root MimeType=inode/directory
> ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin Type=Service X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
> X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
>
> [Desktop Action root] Exec=/usr/bin/pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
> XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
> dolphin Icon=system-file-manager-root Name=Open as administrator

restart dolphin and it should be there with a right click

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1118585/