# Get kdesu working for backups

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, backup, root

I understand from [Kdesu Not Working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044354/kdesu-not-working) that using `kdesu` with GUI programs is not recommended and that usually one might not need it (at least not with kate and konqueror or dolphin). However, when I compare my current hard drive with the backup of my hard drive I need to run [free file sync](https://freefilesync.org/) as root (and do so with `kdesu`). For some reason it is possible to do so from within the KDE Menü, while "kdesu" cannot be found from the command line.

However, I need to start konqueror (and in this case obviously as root) also from within free file sync, so that I can compare some directories manually. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Kdesudo depends on Qt4 which is absent in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This package was [last available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kdesudo) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

So I would recommend to use `pkexec` instead in the way shown below:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY FreeFileSync
```

I have just tested it - FreeFileSync launches normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it. First though: I am not using `kdesudo`, but `kdesu`. Also, I do not have issues starting FreeFileSync, but I have trouble to start konqueror from within FreeFileSync as mentioned in https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=external-applications. I tried your approach though for this by using `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY konqueror "%parent_path%" "%parent_path2%"`, but I got:

Comment: Beendigungscode 1: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[9979:9979:1220/225909.718715:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180. [pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY konqueror "%parent_path%" "%parent_path2%"]

Answer (score 0):

kdesu is "hidden" in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu

Comment: Running `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu konqueror` from the terminal returns `org.kde.kdesu: Daemon not safe (not sgid), not using it.` and exits. If I use "kdesu" in a menu point (modifying the entry in `kmenuedit`), works however. But then I do not need to use the full path that you provided. What do you think of that?