# Rosa Image Writer on Kubuntu 20.04 is missing kdesu

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, sudo

I am using Rosa Image Writer to write ISO images to USB Sticks. The website says that it needs sudoer rights and that kdesu is supported. However on newer Kubuntu versions, kdesu is not available anymore.

Is there a replacement that allows using Rosa Image Writer without starting it from CLI using sudo?

Comment: Have you tried to run it by `sudo ./RosaImageWriter` or `pkexec ./RosaImageWriter`?

Comment: @N0rbert Running it as sudo by CLI works, still this is a workaround only.

Comment: As alternative you can switch to https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/usb-creator-kde .

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5 /path/to/RosaImageWriter` works for me in Kubuntu 21.04. According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044354/kdesu-not-working, kdesu is present but is not in $PATH for security reasons. Using it to run RosaImageWriter seems relatively harmless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That software has not been updated since 2016 according to [their web site](https://abf.io/soft/rosa-imagewriter).

Here is a list of some possible replacements: [ROSA Image Writer Alternatives for Linux](https://alternativeto.net/software/rosa-image-writer/?platform=linux)

According to the above list, [UNetbootin](https://alternativeto.net/software/unetbootin/about/) is very popular. You can find UNetbootin's official website [here](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. By any chance, are you aware if any of those alternatives are available through the standard Kubuntu package sources?

Comment: Sorry I do not.

Comment: I checked... MultiWriter is available.  However it is extremly slow compared to Rosa.