# Why pkexec does not launch Qt-based application as root user?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, sudo, qt, pkexec

Previously it was told that it is bad idea to use `sudo` to launch GUI-based applications.
So one should use `pkexec` instead.

I remembered it, so I tried this to launch Kubuntu Driver Manager on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS using terminal as

```
pkexec kubuntu-driver-manager
```

But this command does not work, it crashes with the following output:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-org.kde.kwin.qpa, dxcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have recently reported [bug 1885615](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1885615). But I'm very surprised with this behavior. And what is interesting `sudo kubuntu-driver-manager` works normally.
I still can launch Gtk-based applications on Kubuntu using `pkexec` - commands like `pkexec pluma` results in opening the application with *root* rights.

So my question is in the title.

Comment: Related: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999).

Comment: @Kulfy, may be. But the main question here - why `pkexec gtk-based-app` works and `pkexec qt-based-app` does not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really there is some kind of [hack](https://askubuntu.com/a/990641/66509) to use `pkexec` instead of `sudo` to launch application without specific PolicyKit *.policy* file. We need to specify missed environment variables as shown below:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY kubuntu-driver-manager
```

Experimentally I discovered that it needs only one `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.policy` file for operation.

Answer (score 4):

To launch a program with `pkexec` a proper `.policy` file for that program needs to be present in the `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` directory. It has nothing to do with which graphical toolkit (Gtk or Qt) is used.

Comment: I have reported previously [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) with special parser [script](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gadmin-samba/+bug/1713311/comments/13) for policykit policy files... Thanks! I forgot this moment.